# Class return statement not printing any output

Tags: python, class, return

I'm learning about Classes and am having a problem with the `return` statement (is it a statement? I hope so), the program prints out nothing, it just ends without doing anything.

```
class className:
    def createName(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def displayName(self):
        return self.name
    def saying(self):
        print("Hello %s" % self.name)

first = className()
second = className()

first.createName("Jack")
second.createName("Joy")

first.displayName()
second.displayName()
```

I know I'm doing something so obviously wrong but I really don't know what. I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Looking briefly at the code it looks like you are calling first.displayName() which simply returns the name. If you want to print something you would either need to call: first.saying() or print("Hello %s" % first.displayName())

Comment: I see, but isn't return supposed to return whatever is in self.name?

Comment: yes it is, but you aren't printing it out anywhere right? You are just returning it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question - `return` does *not* print anything, but it is slightly confusing, since the interactive python prompt *does* print out the value of the last statement e.g.:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1+1
2
```

But if you create a file with contents `1+1` and run it as a python script, nothing is printed.

Since you say that you are a newbie, I'll give you a few pointers on how to improve your code.

```
class className:
    def createName(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def displayName(self):
        return self.name
    def saying(self):
        print("Hello %s" % self.name)
```

`className` has redundancy, you should rename your class just `Name` - also *[new style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)* classes should always inherit `object`, so let's change your definition a bit:

```
class Name(object):
    def createName(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def displayName(self):
        return self.name
    def saying(self):
        print("Hello %s" % self.name)
```

*Creating* something is done *automatically* by overriding the classes `__init__()` method. e.g:

```
class Name(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def displayName(self):
        return self.name
    def saying(self):
        print("Hello %s" % self.name)
```

this way you can already initialize your name when *instantiating* your class, e.g.

```
first = Name("Jack")
```

Second, `display` is handled idiomatically by overriding the method `__repr__` e.g.

```
class Name(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
       return self.name
    def saying(self):
        print("Hello %s" % self.name)
```

This way, you only need to do two things:

```
>>> n = Name("Jack")
>>> print n
Jack
```